# Accessing and modifying array of structures inside function

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble trying to access and modify an array of structures through a function. I'm currently getting an error "expression must be a pointer to a complete type". I would appreciate any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_PRODS = 9;

int main()
{
   int id[NUM_PRODS] = {914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920,
                        921, 922};

   int units[NUM_PRODS] = {842, 416, 127, 514, 437, 269, 97,
                           492, 212};

   double prices[NUM_PRODS] = {12.95, 14.95, 18.95, 16.95, 21.95,
                               31.95, 14.95, 14.95, 16.95};
    
   struct Products {
        int id;
        int units_sold;
        double price;
        double sales;
    };

    Products product_list [NUM_PRODS];

    for (int x = 0 ; x < NUM_PRODS; x++) {
        product_list[x].id = id[x];
        product_list[x].units_sold = units[x];
        product_list[x].price = prices[x];
    }    

   calcSales(NUM_PRODS, product_list);

   return 0;
}

void calcSales(const int NUM_PRODS, struct Products product_list[9])
{
   for (int x = 0 ; x < NUM_PRODS; x++) {
      product_list[x]->sales = product_list[x]->units_sold * product_list[x]->price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take the class and the function out of `main`.

Comment: The code you've posted is missing a `}`. As of right now, `main` never ends.

Comment: Since it is C++ you should be using `std::vector` and `Products` (singular would be better) should have a constructor.

Comment: There are a number of fundamental issues in the shown code regarding scoping and declarations. Functions must be declared before use. Classes and structures declared local to a function are not accessible outside of the function. Etc, etc, etc... All of these issues must be fixed in order for the shown code to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to cigien for the answer, in order to fix the "expression must be a pointer to a complete type" the structure must be outside main; additionally the -> operands should be replaced with "." for accessing the structure elements of the array to create a finished code that will look like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_PRODS = 9;

struct Products {
   int id;
   int units_sold;
   double price;
   double sales;
};

int main()
{
   int id[NUM_PRODS] = {914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920,
                        921, 922};

   int units[NUM_PRODS] = {842, 416, 127, 514, 437, 269, 97,
                           492, 212};

   double prices[NUM_PRODS] = {12.95, 14.95, 18.95, 16.95, 21.95,
                               31.95, 14.95, 14.95, 16.95};
    

Products product_list [NUM_PRODS];

for (int x = 0 ; x < NUM_PRODS; x++) {
    product_list[x].id = id[x];
    product_list[x].units_sold = units[x];
    product_list[x].price = prices[x];
}    

calcSales(NUM_PRODS, product_list);

return 0;
}

void calcSales(const int NUM_PRODS, struct Products product_list[])
{
   for (int x = 0 ; x < NUM_PRODS; x++) {
      product_list[x].sales = product_list[x].units_sold * product_list[x].price;
  

  }
}
```